# Jquery " Close outside" function and hiding container on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to ask, how can i hide some element, using button which previously open this element ?

This code will explain better:

```
<a id="elem-toggle" href="#">filter</a>

<div id="filters">
  <checkbox>
  <checkbox>
  <checkbox>
  <checkbox>
</div>

// Javascript
$('#elem-toggle').on('click', app.toggleFilters);

toggleFilters: function () {
    var filters = $('#filters');
    filters.toggle(0, function () {
        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var filters = $("#filters");
            if (!filters.is(e.target) && filters.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                filters.hide();
                $('#elem-toggle').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, what this code does: clicking on $elem-toggle should show/hide #filters.

But it only opens #filters, but not hide them.

I have used `$(document).mouseup` to hide filters when "click outside" happens.

So basically, i just want to `hide filters on #elem-toggle` as this feature don't work, and i don't know why.

Thank You for reply.

PS: Please, note, that i have used toogle() function in code.

Comment: if you want show and hide you can use `.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#elem-toggle').click(function(){

$('#filters').toggle('slow');


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="elem-toggle" href="#">filter</a>

<div id="filters">
qweqweqweqweq
</div>
```

Try this way.

Use [.toggle()](http://Description:%20Display%20or%20hide%20the%20matched%20elements.)

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Comment: Simple toggle works fine, but please keep in mind that i have used $(document).mouseuup ... to hide element on click for example on body element, but not this element itself. And this causes problems with show hide button - toggling...

Answer (score 0):

as you just want to show or hide the filters why dont you just go for following

```
$('#elem-toggle').on('click',function(){
  $("#filters").toggle();});
```

this should do exactly what you want.